# specify a new world coordinate system in kinect

Tags: computer-vision, kinect

how could I specify a new world coordinate system in kinect? For example, my kinect is moving and i need to specify a static world coordinate system in the scene. If using depth map to identify user specified world coordinate, what is the most accurate way? Since the resolution of depth map is not high, it is difficult to select exact pixels which define the user specified world coordinate. 
what is the best way to convert default world coordinate to this user-specified world coordinate system?

Comment: What language and kinect library are you using ? It should be a matter of simply using a 4x4 transformation matrix (which could already be available in your setup)

Comment: it seems to identify the user specified world coordinate system in depth map is not accurate.

Comment: Let me rephrase: are you using OpenNI, the Kinect for Windows SDK, etc. ? What languague are you writing you're code in ? (c++/java/c#/etc.)

Comment: i am using Kinect SDK and C#

Answer (score 0):

You want to look into transformation matrices. These will allow you to transform a set of coordinates, for instance to rotate, translate, scale, etc. There are various libraries out there that provide matrix structures, like Math.NET Numerics, XNA, etc.

Answer (score 0):

AS Bas mentioned it should be a matter of using a transformation matrix.
In XNA there is a [Matrix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Matrix.aspx) and a [Vector3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.vector3.aspx). There are [other implementations](http://ycouriel.blogspot.co.uk/2010/08/c-matrix-and-vector-representation.html) out there. I don't use C# so I can't advise on which one is the best. However the idea is the same regardless of the library you use: it's just a bit of linear algebra:

1. Use a Matrix instance and it's methods to easily rotate/translate into the coordinate system you need.
2. Multiply the Vector3 instance to the transformation matrix to get a new vector into the new coordinate system. (XNA's Vector3 does that with the [Transform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.vector3.transform.aspx) method as far as I can see in the docs, other implementations might give you a mult()/multiply() or simply support the `*` operator between a vector and a matrix)
3. Optionally, if you want to convert from your custom coordinate space back into the kinect coordinate system, it would a simple matter of getting the inverse of the transformation matrix you created and using that to multiply a vector/position in the custom coordinate system to get a vector in the kinet coordinate system.

The code part is trivial as long as you understand a few concepts in linear algebra(mainly vector and matrices, you might not need quaternions at this stage). There are plenty of resources out there, for example:

1. Personally I found [3D Math Primer](http://gamemath.com/about-the-book/) really easy follow. Although the concepts may appear hard at first, with the visual geometric interpretations the linear algebra made a lot more sense, especially if you think visually
2. [Khan's Academy course on Linear Algebra](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra)
3. Eric Haines(from Autodesk) has Udacity course on [Interactive 3D Graphics](https://www.udacity.com/course/cs291). Very nicely explained and super easy to pick up. It's using three.js/webgl, but you should find some handy information in the Transformations and Matrices lessons.